# Date comparison error with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compare dates in javascript. Why this happend?

```
var strDate = "28/06/2014";
var arrayDate = strDate.split("/");
var fechaTurno = new Date(arrayDate[2], arrayDate[1] - 1, arrayDate[0]);
var fechaActual = new Date();
var fechaLimite = new Date();
fechaLimite.setDate(fechaActual.getDate() + 10);

console.log(fechaTurno); //  Date {Sat Jun 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300}
console.log(fechaActual); //  Date {Fri Jun 27 2014 08:36:24 GMT-0300}
console.log(fechaLimite); //  Date {Mon Jul 07 2014 08:36:24 GMT-0300}

alert(fechaActual.getDate() <= fechaTurno.getDate()); // true
alert(fechaTurno.getDate() <= fechaLimite.getDate()); // false
```

Why the last line is false? Should be true. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code I don't see any error

> getDate Return the day of the month

```
alert(fechaActual.getDate() <= fechaTurno.getDate()); // true  because 27 < 28 
alert(fechaTurno.getDate() <= fechaLimite.getDate()); // false because 28 > 7
```

to compare the whole date try just

```
alert(fechaActual <= fechaTurno); 
alert(fechaTurno <= fechaLimite);
```

Answer (score 3):

`getDate()` method returns the day of the month.

That's it - 28 is not `<=` than 7.

You would know that if you tried to run `fechaTurno.getDate()` separately and see what it returns instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after eliminating `getDate()`

```
alert(fechaActual <= fechaTurno); // true
alert(fechaTurno <=fechaLimite ); //true
```